# переделать в stream

Tags: java

как переписать этот цикл в stream?

```
  public BigDecimal getPreisForAllPets(){
       BigDecimal gesamtPrise = new BigDecimal("0.00");
       for (Pet pet: pets){
          for (Treatment treatment : pet.getTreatments()){
              gesamtPrise =  gesamtPrise.add(treatment.getPreis());
          }
       }
       return gesamtPrise;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public BigDecimal getPreisForAllPets(){
    return pets.stream()
            .map(Pet::getTreatments)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(Treatment::getPreis)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Comment: List::stream подчеркивает красным

Comment: А что у вас возвращает метод `getTreatments`?

Comment: public Collection<Treatment> getTreatments() {
        return treatments;
    }

Comment: написал Cjllection вместо List, все работает, бы бог!